# Un-jailbreak iPhone without updating iOS?

Tags: ios, restore, jailbreak

I have a jailbroken iPhone 6s, running iOS 9.3.3.

An "*Erase all content and settings*" will reset the phone, but will not "un-jailbreak" the phone. I know a factory restore will completely wipe the phone and update the iOS to the latest available (and hence remove the jalbreak), but I want to keep the iPhone on iOS 9.

Is there a way I can un-jailbreak my phone, without having to update the software?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Cydia Eraser](https://cydia.saurik.com/package/com.saurik.impactor/) by Saurik to completely wipe and restore your device to stock iOS without updating.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't. The success of jaibreaking is to only do it on a device that doesnt receive updates often since updating erases the jailbreak.

If you are confident that the update that you wish to go to has a jailbreak (the most recent version of iOS as of the day you choose to update), then you should be ok to jailbreak it back again. That would be the only way to be updated and jailbroken, unfortunately I doubt there is a backup for the latest version of iOS.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. He does not want to update his iPhone and keep the jailbreak. He wants to get rid of the jailbreak and keep the current version.

Comment: You are correct, I did.